# JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT - Options select with (getElementById)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$("tarac").val($("#choosesase  option:selected").length);
```

how can i use above code with document.getElementById

Comment: In what way do you want to use that code (which includes a *replacement* for `getElementById`) **with** `getElementById`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking to implement a muti option based select. If yes, then this snippet should solve it for you. If not, please update your question and add more details, and I'll refine the snippet.

```js
function updateInput () {
             
        var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#element :checked');
    var selected = [...checked].map(option => option.value);  
      document.getElementsByClassName('tarac')[0].value = selected.length;
    };
```

```html
<input class="tarac" value=""/>
<select id="element" multiple onchange=updateInput()>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</select>
```

Comment: my option menu `<tr>
                <td><form:label path="saseNo">Şase Numarası*</form:label></td>
                <td><form:select onchange="selectvalue()" id="choosesase" path="saseNo" multiple="true">
                    <form:options  items="${saseNoList}" />
                </form:select> </td>
            </tr> `

Comment: I wrote your code but it didn't work

Comment: what was the error you got?

Comment: thank you for helping me, it worked `function selectvalue() {
        var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#choosesase :checked');
        var selected = [...checked].map(option => option.value);
        document.getElementById("tarac").value = selected.length;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` which allow you to use `#element  option[selected]` selector :

```
document.querySelector('#tarac').value = document.querySelectorAll('#element  option[checked]').length;
```

Note : I guessed `tarac` is an `id`

Comment: i got an error like this  Pseudo class ':selected' is allowed only in following rules: jquery selector

Comment: I edited, but I'm not sure to understand exactly what ou need, can give some details about what you are trying to di with this code ?

Comment: I want it to write to the "tarac" how many elements I selected from the option menu

Comment: Is your option menu a `select` with `multiple` attribute ?

Comment: yes, multiple .